# Per code-block programming language indication implementation

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If a user had to specify which programming language he/she is using per code-block or if there would be some programming language detection per code-block, would this be of any advantage?

If so, we could have a subtile indication of what programming language is being used for each code-block in a question like this: (photoshopped example/concept)

[image]

I personally think implementing a such feature would:

- Increase answering speed
- Decrease the level of disorder in some cases/questions
- Make UI look a bit more neat

What do you think about the implementation of a such feature? Would it be generally better or worse for Stack Overflow? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Please classify: `printf("Hello world!");` There's  passel of languages that could be...

Comment: Consider `a += b;`. What programming language would you pick? When reading questions I sometimes have to look at the tags to know the language for a snippet.

Comment: Perhaps the feature should be optional?

Comment: I don't get it. *Why* would this do all of those things? Shouldn't it be obvious enough what language the code is in either from reading it or reading the surrounding context? This just seems like a useless gimmick, especially considering how rare it is for answers to contain code in more than 2 languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in comments and Deduplicator's answer, automatic detection is not, in general, feasible.

I think the language is usually clear enough for human readers from a combination of context and tags. If necessary, the poster can include language indications in text: "The following Java program does ...". If a reader cannot tell which language was used there, they can add a comment asking for clarification.

To me, adding a feature for this seems like overkill for a relatively rare problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an example why automatic inference of the language will often be impossible:

```
 #include/*
s='''*/<stdio.h>
main(){char*_;/*==;sub _:lvalue{$_}<<s;#';<<s#'''
def printf(a,*b):print a%b,
s
#*/
_=" #include/*%cs='''*/<stdio.h>%cmain(){char*_;/*==;sub _:lvalue{%c_}<<s;#';<<s#'''%cdef printf(a,*b):print a%%b,%cs%c#*/%c_=%c%s%c;printf(_,10,10,36,10,10,10,10,34,_,34,10,10,10,10);%c#/*%cs='''*/%c}//'''#==%c";printf(_,10,10,36,10,10,10,10,34,_,34,10,10,10,10);
#/*
s='''*/
}//'''#==
```

That is a [polyglot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polyglot) [quine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quine) from here: http://shinh.skr.jp/obf
It works at least in: [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)

It gets even worse with snippets (prevalent on SO) and errors (also quite common, especially in questions).